# Proving limit using definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta, rational-functions

I need to prove $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\ 0}\frac{x^2-8}{{x-8}} =1 $$ using epsilon-delta definition.
I know I need to show that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exist a $\delta >0$ such that if $|x|<\delta$, then $| {\frac{x^2-8}{x-8}}-1|<\epsilon$

WHat I did:

$|{\frac{x^2-8}{x-8}}-1|=|{\frac{x^2-x}{x-8}}|$, but Im having troubles now deciding what my delta should be.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me an explanation on how should I choose delta and why.
Thanks.

Comment: What does $x^-8$ mean? It looks like a typo...

Comment: Is $\frac{x-8}{\sqrt{x-8}}$? if so, it is the same as $\sqrt{x-8}$

Comment: sorry I had typing error. edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$\frac{x^2-x}{x-8}=x\frac{x-1}{x-8}.$$Now, if $|x|<1$, then $-1<x<1$ and therefore you have two things:

- $-9<x-8<-7$, which implies that $|x-8|>7$;
- $-2<x-1<0$, which implies that $|x-1|<2$.

So,$$|x|<1\implies\left|x\frac{x-1}{x-8}\right|<\frac27|x|.$$Therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min\left\{\frac72\varepsilon,1\right\}$and then\begin{align}|x|<\delta&\implies|x|<\frac72\varepsilon\quad\text{and}\quad|x|<1\\&\implies\left|x\frac{x-1}{x-8}\right|<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\left|\frac{x^2-x}{x-8}\right| = |x|\cdot \left|\frac{x-1}{x-8}\right|.$$

Now, if $\delta<1$, then you can further estimate that:

1. $|x-1| < 3$
2. $|x-8| > 6$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\left|x^2-x\over x-8\right|=|x|\left|x-1\over x-8\right|\le|x|{|x|+1\over||x|-8|}$$

Now the main thing that causes a problem is the smallness of the denominator if $|x|\approx8$. But since we're interested in the limit as $x\to0$, it's easy to stay away from $8$ by requiring, say $|x|\le7$, in which case we have

$${|x|+1\over||x|-8|}\le{7+1\over|7-8|}=8$$

So taking $\delta=\min(7,\epsilon/8)$ we have

$$0\lt|x|\lt\delta\implies\left|x^2-x\over x-8\right|\le8|x|\lt8\delta\le\epsilon$$

as desired.

Remark: The key to limit write-ups of this type is to keep in mind that even though we're thinking of *small* epsilons, we don't want to be embarrassed by claiming an implication that isn't true in case someone decides to use a large $\epsilon$. E.g., if we just let $\delta=\epsilon/8$, we run the risk of the *false* implication $0\lt|x|\lt8\implies|(x^2-x)/(x-8)|\lt64$, which is falsified, for example, at $x=7.9$ (that is, $0\lt|7.9|\lt8$ but $|(7.9^2-7.9)/(7.9-8)|=545.1\gt64$). The role of the "min" is to avoid such false claims. As the other answers here show, there is no single prefered way to choose your delta; it's somewhat a matter of taste. My preference is to try to isolate what causes things to be uncontrollably large, usually a potential zero in a denominator, impose a restriction brings that term under control, and then look at what happens to everything else.

Answer (score 0):

We've solved the problem on scrap paper and now present a solution devoid of the process details.

It is easy to show that

$\quad \large |x| \lt \frac{1}{6} \implies |\frac{x-1}{x-8}|  \lt \frac{1}{7}$

For $\varepsilon \gt 0$ set $\delta = \text{min}(\frac{1}{6}, 7\varepsilon)$.

If $x \lt \delta$ then

$\quad \large |{\frac{x^2-8}{x-8}-1|=| \frac{x-1}{x-8}}|\,|x| \lt \frac{1}{7} \cdot 7\varepsilon = \varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get an upper bound for $\left| \frac{x-1}{x-8} \right|$ when $x$ is sufficiently small. A couple of things you can do to make this easier: 1) Use the triangle inequality, as one of the answerers did; 2) separate a constant so that you only need to deal with one term involving $x$. So if $|x| < 1$ then

$$\left| \frac{x-1}{x-8} \right|=\left| 1+\frac{7}{x-8} \right| \le 1+\frac{7}{8-x} \le 1+\frac{7}{8-1}=2.$$

Then you have $\delta = \min \left(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right).$